# View VBA script of .doc file in MS Word 2010

Tags: vba, ms-word, doc

How can I view VBA script of .doc file in MS Word 2010?

Comment: Do you have an installation of Word, or is the problem to extract the code from the `.doc` without using Word?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In "customize ribbon" I had to check the "developer tools". After that the developer tab appeared, and it has all the functions I need.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a programming question. Find the office 2010 equivalent to "Tools"->"Macro"->"Visual Basic Editor".

Answer (score -1):

In Search bar start to type "Visual Basic Editor", you would see the link in suggestions which would allow to open it.
[image: Search for Visual Basic]